# Upsample data and interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have the following dataframe:

```
Month   Col_1    Col_2

1       0,121    0,123
2       0,231    0,356
3       0,150    0,156
4       0,264    0,426
...
```

I need to resample this to weekly resolution and to interpolate between the points. The latter part, the interpolation is straight-forward. The reindex part is a bit tricky, on the other hand, at least for me.

If I use the DataFrame.reindex() method, it will only erase all the entries from the dataframe. I have tried to do it manually, by using .loc() to create new 'NaN' entries between each consecutive months, but this method overwrites the entries I already have.

Any clue how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Your weekly resolution depends on which months these are.  You've only provided integers.

Comment: well, this is how I got the data, it's the calendar order. should I convert to datetime index first? in that case, how does the resample deal with the interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume a start date, I chose `2009-12-31`.

To get `resample` to work, you need a `pd.DateTimeIndex`.

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-12-31')
df.Month = df.Month.apply(lambda x: start_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x))
df = df.set_index('Month')

df.resample('W').interpolate()
```

[image]

---

#### Replicable code

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """Month   Col_1    Col_2
1       0,121    0,123
2       0,231    0,356
3       0,150    0,156
4       0,264    0,426"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), decimal=',', delim_whitespace=True)

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2009-12-31')
df.Month = df.Month.apply(lambda x: start_date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x))
df = df.set_index('Month')

df.resample('W').interpolate()
```

Comment: great! it does exactly what I need, even though the inferior part of the dataframe has something against it. anyway, I couldn't run it, I get an 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'month''. I tried to use df['Month'] insead of df.Month, and it still kicks an error. Any idea?

Comment: @davidr if that is a direct copy/paste, I noticed that month is lower case.

Comment: no, no, it's capital. the code I used is a direct copy paste of what you've written here. Anyway, I tried to create a new column, an empty one, before that method. this is what I get: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: ahh, I think it's the commas.  I'll add the same exact code I used to copy your data and how I messaged it.  BTW, this is a case in point why  it's a good idea to post the code that generates the data.  One moment.

Comment: the last version of the code works, thank you. Still, I am reading the data from a .csv file, in which the decimal sign is the point, not comma. I will try run it from another station, maybe the way Anacondas is set on this PC messes up something. Thank you again for you patience and for showing me the way of solving it.

Comment: @davidr if this answered you question, don't forget to mark it as the answer.